# proof of Perron's formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was reading a journal entry on the proof of Perron's formula, and I got stuck on one of the computations. The following is the journal entry itself:

[image]

[image]

The part I have a problem with is where they make an estimate on the first sum in (3.4). **How did they get $\log x/n$?**

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite and expand the Dirichlet series.
$$
f(s)x^s = \sum \frac{a_n}{n^s} x^s = \sum a_n \left( \frac{x}{n} \right)^s,$$
so now $\frac{x}{n}$ plays the role of $y$ in the integral. You had $\log y$ before. You you have $\log x/n$.

Comment: Thanks, and, yes, I do see that part. Maybe my question was wrong in some sense then. Could you please tell me as to why they put that here? The original article is at: http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/pamq/2007/0003/0002/PAMQ-2007-0003-0002-a004.pdf